# (Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationException):Element 'head': Character content other than whitespace is not allowed

Tags: magento2.3.2

***Can anyone help me, I'm having this error, right after adding a folder in magento root***

```
Magento/->app/->/code/-> Bag(Mycustom) .. mgento232
```

> The message that appears is : 1 exception(s): Exception #0
>   (Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationException): Element 'head':
>   Character content other than whitespace is not allowed because the
>   content type is 'element-only'. Line: 752

.... Can help me pLEASE

Is magento 2.3.2

Comment: There may be something wrong in new module's layout xml file

Comment: Please help with some examples of what the file or folder should look like.

Comment: Do you have any file here ? Please check file in this location.. **app/code/Bag/Mycustom/view/frontend/layout**

Comment: Did you checked then ?

Comment: yes i have file ... i checked yes

Comment: Can you please let me know that in which URL you're getting this error ? like **www.example.com/customer/account/create**

Comment: I want to send screenshot about it , Where can I send?

Comment: You can attach ss in question

Comment: I do not need ss if you'll send URL that is okay.

Comment: I use localhost to create my page white magento .. URL is @localhost/mypagemagento

Comment: is there **any mypagemagento_index_index.xml** file available ?

Comment: Not, i dont have any file white this

Comment: I'm asking URL of where you're getting this error. Can you please share that with me ? otherwise please let me know how many .xml files are available there ?

Comment: When trying to try page ..Logo on home page that appears or error